# Spotfire TERR script to check if date string is within date range

Tags: spotfire

```
startDate="04/01/2015"
endDate="07/01/2015"
dateString="04/30/2015 03/21/2015 06/28/2015 12/19/2015"
```

I want to have a calculated column which returns a "Yes" if all dates in dateString are between startDate and endDate, and a "No" otherwise.

Please note: dateString can have any number of dates.

I tried writing a TERR script(return type String):

```
MyCustomFunction <- function(startDate, endDate, dateString) {
    v1 <- scan(text=dateString, what='', quiet=TRUE)
    v2 <- as.Date(v1, '%m/%d/%Y')
    temp <- v2 >= as.Date(startDate, '%m/%d/%Y') & v2 <= as.Date(endDate,'%m/%d/%Y')
    ifelse(length(unique(temp))==1, ifelse(unique(temp)==TRUE, test<-as.character(TRUE), test<-as.character(FALSE)), test<-as.character(FALSE))
    test
}
output <- MyCustomFunction(startDate = input1, endDate = input2, dateString = input3)
```

But this displays an empty column.
Can anybody help me with this? Or provide an alternate solution? I use Spotfire version 6.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by any number of dates? Do you mean different date formats? Or do you mean that the date range might be different? Also are the dateStrings located in a string column?

Comment: @phiver
By any number of dates, I meant dateString could be any of the following:

"04/30/2015 03/21/2015 06/28/2015 12/19/2015" OR
"04/30/2015 03/21/2015" OR
"04/30/2015 03/21/2015 06/28/2015" OR
"04/30/2015"....

The date formats are always the same. And yes, the date string column is of type string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your code a bit. Spotfire sets the input as a vector. Adjust inputs and outputs as you want them to be. I used strsplit because I assume the data looks like this.[image]

also there is no need for assignments inside your ifelse statement. You just assign the outcome to your variable. I tested this code in Spotfire 6.5 and I get the correct results back.

```
startDate <- "01/01/2015"
endDate <- "07/01/2015"

MyCustomFunction <- function(startDate, endDate, dateString) {
      outcome <- NULL
      for (i in 1:length(dateString)) {
      v1 <- strsplit(dateString[i], " ", fixed = TRUE)
      v2 <- as.Date(unlist(v1), '%m/%d/%Y')
      temp <- v2 >= as.Date(startDate, '%m/%d/%Y') & v2 <= as.Date(endDate,'%m/%d/%Y')
      outcome <- c(test, ifelse(length(unique(temp))==1, ifelse(unique(temp)==TRUE, as.character(TRUE), as.character(FALSE)), as.character(FALSE)))
      }
      return(outcome)
}

output <- MyCustomFunction(startDate, endDate, dateString)
```

Comment: this works, but just found out that Spotfire takes lots of time to create the calculated column, probably because there's about 25,000 odd records. Can you think of a faster alternative?